# is it possible to create multuple desision tree models in spark mlib

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a data of players and features and I need to create different tree for each player based on its features. Lets assume we have millions for rows per player.

Is it possible to somehow harness Spark MLlib for that?

I know there is an option to run on a data frame in a loop filter different player each time and fit the model on the filtered data, but this is quite slow and not uses spark parallelism capabilities

Comment: I encountered a similar use-case a while ago. Found that I was fighting against the Spark API. Moreover this approach creates a lot of state in the form of many many models. I'll be watching this question with interest.

Comment: Hi guys, anybody found a solution for this?